# Why my page gives me 404

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I create a new controller in codeIgniter:

```
class Get extends CI_Controller{

    public function up(){
        $this->load->view('get_view.php');
    }

}
```

And this is my view that executes only a javascript operation:

```
<script src="/js/update.php" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php
?>
<script>
updateDB();
</script>
```

Now I modify my routes in this way:

```
$route['get']='get/up';
```

But when I go to the link "localhost/get", it gives me a 404.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should go to `localhost/get` (or `localhost/index.php/get`) for your route to call the correct controller. What is "index_page"?

Comment: And the route is defined as `get/up` while you are accessing it as `/get`

Comment: If you go to localhost, do you see the default_controller?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your url helper autoloaded

Your are loading a php in javascript I would think instead of update.php then best update.js

Then try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/update.js');?>" ></script>
```

Assets folder in main directory.

**Update:**

Make sure also your class and file names of models and controllers make sure the first letter is uppercase example Welcome.php and not welcome.php

Comment: yes but it doesn't work. I give 404 when I call my controller. I modify the code with your suggests but it the same think!

Comment: Another thing in codeigniter you do not need .php when load view like your done, `$this->load->view('get_view.php');` to $this->load->view('get_view');

Comment: Just thinking If you have not removed index.php from your config you also would need htaccess for that as well.  Then you will need to include index.php in url `http://localhost/project/index.php/get`